# HTML - the space between inline-block divs

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML file with 2 types of divs, all of them are 15 x 15px, some of them red, the others green.

How can I eliminate that white space between the lines? I tried to add `padding: 2px;`, there is no space after that, but the divs are getting bigger than I want. How can I get rid of that space, keeping the size I want(15 x 15px) for the divs?

```css
div {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: -2px;
}
.used {
  background-color: red;
}
.free {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>

<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>

<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>

<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>

<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>

<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>

<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>

<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>

<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>

<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>

<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>

<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>

<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>

<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>

<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>

<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>

<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>

<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>

<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>

<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>

<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>

<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>

<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>

<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>

<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>

<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>

<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>

<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>

<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>

<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="free"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
<div class="used"></div>
```

Comment: Please post *actual* markup, not images of markup.

Comment: This is not duplicate. His problem is that he set margins on top and bottom. You need to set your margin this way: div {height: 15px; width: 15px; display: inline-block; margin: 0 -2px 0 -2px;}

Comment: or     margin: 0 -4px 0 0;

Comment: @Valius79, It still doesn't work.

Comment: @Scott, I added the code.

Comment: @Valius79 - you *sure* about that? https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5dbLm874/

Comment: @j08691, I tried that before, but if you look closely there is still a problem. Just look at the size of the squares(divs) on the first and last row. See the difference?

Comment: No, what should I be seeing? And BTW, your layout is dependent on the width of the user's browser. Also, in my fiddle I left the margin you set in your code. Probably wanna remove that.

Comment: Ok, I achieved what you wanted by doing adding margin 0 and line height to the body element. body {
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 0;
}

Comment: @j08691 just pointed out that what I claimed was fix wasn't, and he was right. I tested with one row only. The comment above worked for me on my comp.

Comment: @Valius79 this _is_ a duplicate. This is the between-inline-elements whitespace issue covered in the answer to the linked question

Comment: Oh, my bad. Sorry for wasting your time guys!

Comment: @j08691 Yes, I had to remove the margin, it looks good now. Thanks for that!

Comment: @Valius79 all good!